# I want to find Horizontal Straight Line pattern in dataset based on value and DateTime

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

i want to know if one value is in the sequence that all value in this sequence are almost equal.
for example if threshold is '0.02' if difference between value and previous value is less than '0.02' this value are Almost equal
my dataset is like this :

```
create table #temp(rn int,snap_DateTime datetime,value real)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(1,'Nov  9 2014 12:00AM',11.9018)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(2,'Nov  9 2014 12:09AM',13.2106)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(3,'Nov  9 2014 12:18AM',13.5882)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(4,'Nov  9 2014 12:27AM',12.587)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(5,'Nov  9 2014 12:36AM',14.6033)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(6,'Nov  9 2014 12:45AM',14.834)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(7,'Nov  9 2014 12:54AM',14.7367)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(8,'Nov  9 2014  1:03AM',14.3165)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(9,'Nov  9 2014  1:12AM',15.8682)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(10,'Nov  9 2014  1:21AM',11.4258)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(11,'Nov  9 2014  1:30AM',11.7084)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(12,'Nov  9 2014  1:39AM',10.7714)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(13,'Nov  9 2014  1:48AM',8.40939)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(14,'Nov  9 2014  1:57AM',8.98969)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(15,'Nov  9 2014  2:06AM',16.8318)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(16,'Nov  9 2014  2:15AM',18.9059)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(17,'Nov  9 2014  2:24AM',18.8377)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(18,'Nov  9 2014  2:33AM',18.1958)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(19,'Nov  9 2014  2:42AM',16.7439)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(20,'Nov  9 2014  2:51AM',15.2362)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(21,'Nov  9 2014  3:00AM',16.8727)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(22,'Nov  9 2014  3:09AM',16.416)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(23,'Nov  9 2014  3:18AM',16.3363)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(24,'Nov  9 2014  3:28AM',16.0932)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(25,'Nov  9 2014  3:37AM',16.9407)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(26,'Nov  9 2014  3:46AM',17.0356)
insert into #temp(rn ,snap_DateTime ,value ) values(27,'Nov  9 2014  3:55AM',15.9732)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly then use this

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE
    (
      rn INT ,
      snap_DateTime DATETIME ,
      value REAL
    )
INSERT  INTO @temp
        ( rn, snap_DateTime, value )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Nov  9 2014 12:00AM', 11.9018 ),
        ( 2, 'Nov  9 2014 12:09AM', 13.2106 ),
        ( 3, 'Nov  9 2014 12:18AM', 13.5882 ),
        ( 4, 'Nov  9 2014 12:27AM', 13.5882 ),
        ( 5, 'Nov  9 2014 12:36AM', 14.6033 ),
        ( 6, 'Nov  9 2014 12:45AM', 14.834 ),
        ( 7, 'Nov  9 2014 12:54AM', 14.7367 ),
        ( 8, 'Nov  9 2014  1:03AM', 14.3165 ),
        ( 9, 'Nov  9 2014  1:12AM', 15.8682 ),
        ( 10, 'Nov  9 2014  1:21AM', 11.4258 ),
        ( 11, 'Nov  9 2014  1:30AM', 11.7084 ),
        ( 12, 'Nov  9 2014  1:39AM', 10.7714 ),
        ( 13, 'Nov  9 2014  1:48AM', 8.40939 ),
        ( 14, 'Nov  9 2014  1:57AM', 8.98969 ),
        ( 15, 'Nov  9 2014  2:06AM', 16.8318 ),
        ( 16, 'Nov  9 2014  2:15AM', 18.9059 ),
        ( 17, 'Nov  9 2014  2:24AM', 18.8377 ),
        ( 18, 'Nov  9 2014  2:33AM', 18.1958 ),
        ( 19, 'Nov  9 2014  2:42AM', 16.7439 ),
        ( 20, 'Nov  9 2014  2:51AM', 15.2362 ),
        ( 21, 'Nov  9 2014  3:00AM', 16.8727 ),
        ( 22, 'Nov  9 2014  3:09AM', 16.416 ),
        ( 23, 'Nov  9 2014  3:18AM', 16.3363 ),
        ( 24, 'Nov  9 2014  3:28AM', 16.0932 ),
        ( 25, 'Nov  9 2014  3:37AM', 16.9407 ),
        ( 26, 'Nov  9 2014  3:46AM', 17.0356 ),
        ( 27, 'Nov  9 2014  3:55AM', 15.9732 )

-- first vatiant (2012 and earliest)
SELECT  T.rn ,
        T.snap_DateTime ,
        T.value ,
        CASE WHEN ABS(T.Value - COALESCE(lead(T.VALUE) OVER ( ORDER BY rn ), 0)) < 0.02
                  OR ABS(T.Value - COALESCE(lag(T.VALUE) OVER ( ORDER BY rn ),
                                            0)) < 0.02 THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'N'
        END
FROM    @temp AS T

--second variant (for older than 2012 version)

SELECT  A.rn ,
        A.snap_DateTime ,
        A.value ,
        CASE WHEN ABS(A.value - COALESCE(B.value, 0)) < 0.02
                  OR ABS(A.value - COALESCE(C.value, 0)) < 0.02 THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'N'
        END
FROM    @temp AS A
        LEFT JOIN @temp AS B ON ( A.RN + 1 ) = B.RN
        LEFT JOIN @temp AS C ON ( A.RN - 1 ) = C.RN
```

output result

[image]

Comment: vasily thank you for your reply. your suggestion solve half of problem.but i want if current row is in the sequence i want to  flag previous row too.

Comment: if  result of case is 'Y' then i want 'Y' for both current row and Followoing row not only for current row.Your suggestion only flag current row(for both lag and lead)

Comment: @abianari see updated post, two variants with same output result as in screenshot posted

Comment: ,instead of coalesce we cant use lag(T.value,1,0) or lead(T.value,1,0) .again thank you alot

Comment: @abianari, sorry, I'm not understand your comment, what do you mean?

Comment: lead or lag function themselves can manage null (with  'default' value) LAG (scalar_expression [,offset] [,default])
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )

Comment: @abianari ahh, yes, it's whatever you like, you could use `coalesce`, `nullif`, `isnull`, `case when value is null then 0 else value end`, or like you already said option of the function, this just matter of habit) I prefer `coalesce` because you can use several verifications, e.g. `select coalesce(Null,Null,Null,'Z')` return 'Z'. Also one function `lag` is enough, just on `order by` need to set `desc` and lag will works as `lead` or vise versa for the `lead` function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72471/discussion-between-vasily-and-abianari).